# Nest 1.2.1 geographic FilterDescriptor - how to choose operator?

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

We're moving from Nest 1.0.0 to 1.2.1, and I'm having trouble figuring out how to use different geographic operators.

Previously, I had this line of code:

```
f.GeoShape(fieldName, geo => geo.Coordinates(points).Type("polygon").Relation("intersects"));
```

Where f is an empty FilterDescriptor, and points is an

```
IEnumerable<IEnumerable<IEnumerable<double>>>
```

But there is no GeoShape in Nest 1.2.1. The closest thing I found was GeoShapePolygon, but it doesn't accept an operator as a parameter, and I need to use different operators (previously used "within", "intersects", and "disjoint").

How can I achieve this functionality in Nest 1.2.1?

Comment: Hey Michal, thanks for pointing this out.  Looks like NEST is missing the `Relation` option.  I just opened [#1090](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-net/issues/1090) to add support for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fixed in the latest release of NEST, 1.3.1: https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-net/issues/1090